# Prove that (MB (φ))^k = MB (φ^k)

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let V be a K vector space with base B: = {b1,…, bn} and φ an endomorphism in V with a representation matrix MB(φ). Prove that (MB(φ))^k = MB(φ^k) for k = 1, ..., n applies.

Comment: Please format your mathematical expressions correctly; you might find the [instructions here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful. In particular, it's not clear what $MB(\varphi)$ is supposed to be; perhaps that's $M_{\mathcal B}(\varphi)$ (i.e. `M_{\mathcal B}(\varphi)`), but we can't read your mind. Also, please provide some context for this question. What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: i don't understand how to prove that. i need an approach

Comment: How to prove what, exactly? As I said, it's not clear what you mean by $MB(\varphi)$. It would help if you formatted your question correctly, but perhaps you can just explicitly state what you mean by $MB(\varphi)$.

Comment: Try to think at the definition of the representation matrix and what is the meaning of each column. Maybe try an induction on k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the diagram below is commutative and thus compatible with compositions of endomorphisms composing the squares next to one another(especially with $\varphi \circ \varphi$)

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V@>{\varphi}  >> V \\
@VVBV  @VVBV  \\
K^n @>{MB(φ)}>> K^n
\end{CD}
$$

here $B: V \to K^n$ identifies $V$ with $K^n$ by identifying $b_i$ with $e_i=(0,0,...,1,...,0)$. Composing this squares gives you the result you are looking for

Comment: could the downvoter tell me why the -1?

Comment: I think that the question and the tags shows that the mathematic background of *mathslooser* is limited to linear algebra and he is searching for an answer that uses only the basic definition of representation matrix. I think that giving an answer expressed with the composition of commutative diagrams is not useful for him.

Comment: as I learned linear algebra the representation matrix MB(φ) occured at first time I ever have seen it in such square.

Comment: Well, this sound strange to me, i think that for this kind of answer can be very confusing for a new learner thinking to this with this squares; but maybe in different places there are different ways to see or teaching things. I will remove your -1. Oh, I can't, sorry.

Comment: I have to confess that my linear algebra prof is indeed a homological algebraist :)

Comment: @NotPhiQuadro you should be able to remove it by clicking on the arrow again

Comment: It says that my vote is locked until the question is edited

Comment: thank u so much!! it helps me a lot.